# Can I minify JavaScript or aspx code in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, minify

I'm developing a web app using C# and MS VS 2010 IDE. The project has several of my own .js files in the Scripts folder that are designed to run on a client-side browser. While writing them I gave each variable and function in the JavaScript meaningful names and used plenty of comments.

So I was wondering, can I minify those .js files before publishing them (or uploading to a production web server) in Visual Studio 2010?

PS. It would be also helpful to minify aspx files as well...

Comment: there are a lot of special tools for this, in VS you can do only some simple like removing extra spaces, new line symbols, tabs, comments, etc... using VS regexp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several libraries listed on the [NuGet Gallery for minification](http://www.nuget.org/List/Search?searchTerm=tag%3a%20minify).

They will all deal with javascript and css, but none will minify the aspx markup.

Comment: Are there any specific ones that you used and would recommend? (Not to make a commercial for anyone, let's name only free ones.)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this doesn't sound like too much of a commercial but I do recommend my own OSS project [RequestReduce](http://requestreduce.com). It minifies and merges CSS and JS files (or any css or js mime typed file) on the fly at run time (caching them of course). It also generates optimized sprites of most css background images. Currently it does not minify html but that is on my backlog. The features that make [RequestReduce](http://requestreduce.com) stad out from the rest is that it does not require any code changes and extremely minimal configuration. In fact if you are using nuget, there may be nothing more to do than install the package. It also works with CDNs and web farms. It has been adopted by many of the MSDN and Technet web applications (forums, search, galleries). I have seen some page load times cut in half using this. And of course it is absolutely free.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. If it's free, how do you keep developing it? )) OK, now seriously, does it integrate with VS2010?

Comment: Its a labor of love :) It does not integrate with vs2010  per se. It works at run time and I think most likely accomplishes in the end what you are looking for - the minification of your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will do everything your looking for but I like to use Chirpy. You can find it at:

http://chirpy.codeplex.com/

It is really easy to use to minify js, css, and combine them into one file. It will also minify js and css in the aspx file.

Look at the documentation page and follow the three links (reverse order is better) to see what it can do.